# Can I condense this two functions into one?

Tags: jquery

Because one is on ready and the other is on resize, is it possible to condense the two?

```
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    var $div = $('#wrapper .col');
    var max = 0;
    $.each($div , function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight()) > max){
        max = parseInt($(this).outerHeight())
      }
    });
    $("#wrapper").css('height', max + 'px');
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    var $div = $('#wrapper .col');
    var max = 0;
    $.each($div, function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight()) > max){
        max = parseInt($(this).outerHeight())
        $("#wrapper").css('height', max + 'px');
      }
    });
  });
```

This works the way it is but I'd like to do something like:

```
  function resize(){
    var $div = $('#wrapper .col');
    var max = 0;
    $.each($div, function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight()) > max){
        return parseInt($(this).outerHeight())
        $("#wrapper").css('height', max + 'px');
      }
    });
  }


  $(window).on('load', function(){
    $("#wrapper").css('height', resize() + 'px');
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    $("#wrapper").css('height', resize() + 'px');
  });
```

This doesn't work however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach load and resize in the on method with a space like this:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
```

you need also to bind resize() method at the end:

```
}).resize();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I could do that. Thanks. I'll try it now.

Comment: C-Link, There is a problem with the resizing after I attach both load and resize.

Comment: Thanks C-link, that worked. Weird that I'd have to call `.resize()` afterwards tho

Answer (score 1):

Please read the **[docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

The method takes following parameters:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

You can see that events is plural as well as the description stated:

> One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such
>   as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

So you can do:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){ 
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, Felix. I'll have a look at it now. I'm still pretty new to JQ

Answer (score 0):

you can also use bind

```
$(window).bind('load resize',
```